# code working in chrome console but not in page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I'm trying to assign a function to a button using javascript, but for some reason it's not working. This is the button in question. At this point I'm just trying to make it responsive.

```
<button id="artbtn" class="artbtn btn">Art</button>
```

In the Chrome developer console I tried this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("artbtn")[0].addEventListener(
"click", function(){
    alert("hi")
})
```

and it did what I wanted, it threw up an alert. But when I tried using that script on the page... no response.

I'm using angular v1.2.7 with node.js which probably is contributing to this but I'm not sure what exactly is happening.

Comment: Are you making sure to have the `<button>` loaded **before** the code is run

Comment: how would I make sure the button is loaded?

Comment: also yeah probably I'll have to look up documentation on ng-click. I'm trying to understand angular so I should probably do that anyway.

Comment: General rule - 99.9% of the time, unless you're writing a directive, there's a better way to do things than direct DOM manipulation in Angular.

Comment: yeah probably, I'm just still very confused about directives.

Answer (score 2):

Best way to do this the angular way is to use ng-click

```
<button id="artbtn" class="artbtn btn" ng-click="clickHandler($event)">Art</button>
```

You will need to add the clickHandler function to your scope in your controller:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.clickHandler = function (event) {
    alert('hi');
  }
});
```

[Here is a working plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/DifSjUAqswzXikSclOeA?p=preview)